# Laravel and php wrapper for youtube-dl norkunas / youtube-dl-php

Tags: laravel, youtube-dl

I'm using Laravel Version 6.14.0 and I wanted to use the following Youtube-dl wrapper for PHP from https://github.com/norkunas/youtube-dl-php in Laravel.

I used the command `composer require norkunas/youtube-dl-php` to install it and I got the following output :

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/options-resolver (v4.4.4): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing norkunas/youtube-dl-php (v1.4.0): Downloading (100%)         
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

This is what my Controller looks like

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\YtScreen;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use YoutubeDl\YoutubeDl;
use YoutubeDl\Exception\CopyrightException;
use YoutubeDl\Exception\NotFoundException;
use YoutubeDl\Exception\PrivateVideoException;


class YtScreenController extends Controller
{


    public function frontpage()
    {

        $dl = new YoutubeDl([
        'continue' => true, // force resume of partially downloaded files. By default, youtube-dl will resume downloads if possible.
        'format' => 'bestvideo',
    ]);
    // For more options go to https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#user-content-options

    $dl->setDownloadPath('/home/user/downloads');
    // Enable debugging
    $dl->debug(function ($type, $buffer) {
        if (\Symfony\Component\Process\Process::ERR === $type) {
            echo 'ERR > ' . $buffer;
        } else {
            echo 'OUT > ' . $buffer;
        }
    });
    try {
        $video = $dl->download('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDAw7vW7H0c');
        echo $video->getTitle(); // Will return Phonebloks
        // $video->getFile(); // \SplFileInfo instance of downloaded file
    } catch (NotFoundException $e) {
        // Video not found
    } catch (PrivateVideoException $e) {
        // Video is private
    } catch (CopyrightException $e) {
        // The YouTube account associated with this video has been terminated due to multiple third-party notifications of copyright infringement
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Failed to download
    }


        return view("frontpage");

    }

}
```

The problem is that the newly installed php wrapper doesn't work at all. I don't even get an error message. No video gets downloaded, no error message is shown ... nothing happens. The controller itself is fine , I tested it with a different function.

I assume I didn't include the files correctly since I don't even get an error message. Has anyone made a similiar expirience and knows how to get this php wrapper for youtube-dl to work in Laravel? Or maybe has an alternative idea for a different youtube-dl php wrapper.

Comment: Can you `dd($e)` from every `catch`?

Comment: Thanks ! That actually got me an error message to work with. The wrapper couldn't find and start youtube-dl . Had to set the path $dl->setBinPath('/snap/bin/youtube-dl') and it worked